# InputSelect - validation not working as expected

Tags: c#, validation, input, .net-core, blazor

I'm having issues with a step in one of my multi-page-forms.
Lets say the below code shows form-page #2 and I've just pressed the back-button (gone from form-page #3 to #2).
The AppData holds the data i stored from the first time I completed the #2 form, and the "if" makes sure the previous choice is the selected one.

```
<EditForm Model="FormModel" OnValidSubmit="HandleValidSubmit">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <ValidationSummary />
    <InputSelect @bind-Value="FormModel.StudyLocation">
        <optgroup label="StudyPlace">
            <option selected disabled hidden>Choose place</option>
            @foreach (var studyPlace in StudyPlaces)
            {
                if (AppData.HousingTestWhere != null && AppData.HousingTestWhere.StudyLocation == studyPlace)
                {
                    <option selected value="@studyPlace">@studyPlace</option>
                }
                else
                {
                    <option value="@studyPlace">@studyPlace</option>
                }
            }
        </optgroup>
    </InputSelect>
    <button type="submit">Neste</button>
</EditForm>
```

The problem is the following: 
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aIkmW.png)

The previously selected item is selected/default when going from page #3 to #2, but when attempting to go back to page #3 (without re-selecting anything in the dropdown) the validation complains that "nothing has been selected" or something.. even though a element clearly has the selected tag.

What do?

Comment: It's not really clear what you mean by `page #N` or how you load/reload the FormModel etc. Consider ceating a new minimal project and post the exact steps to reproduce this. See [mcve]

Comment: Also note that the whole if-else part is unnecesary, you have a two way binding. Just make sure `FormModel.StudyLocation` is initialzied correctly. You only need the else part.